# iOS 11 UISearchController disappearing when typing

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

iOS 11 search bar keeps disappearing when typing i have tried to set the `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false` also the `searchController.definesPresentationContext = true` here is a video of what is going on

### [Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wbmj8TtMkgrgVK1-_BhHhg-fHIUT5Grt)

My delegate function

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filarr = arr.filter({ (arr:String) -> Bool in
        if arr.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!){
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }

    })
    resultController.tableView.reloadData()
}

//Assigning the searchbarcontroller
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
```

Comment: Have you added anything in your delegate methods if yes add it in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: how and where are you assigning your `UISearchController`?

Comment: In the ViewDidload i updated the question @RobK

Comment: are you actually setting your `searchResultsUpdater` and `searchBar.delegate` delegates?

Comment: Yes i am sure i am setting them

Comment: did you define `searchController` as a class variable or inside `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set `definesPresentationContext` to `true` on the view controller which presents your `searchController`.

Your are doing this:

```
searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
```

but should do this:

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add in **viewDidLoad()** :

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```